# How do you earn the Row of Many Candles hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017, secret-hat

I earned the Row of Many Candles hat on the [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) today. It's categorized as a 'secret hat' so it doesn't give a description for why it's awarded.

What is this the Row of Many Candles hat awarded for?

[image]

Comment: What's nice about the hat is the fact that it fits perfectly atop [community ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)!

Comment: You earned it but you're not wearing it! Much disappointed ... :(

Comment: It is a secret hat, so we can't tell you, otherwise it would not be secret anymore.

Comment: Looks good on You!

Comment: I too got this hat :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As you can see from the list of 
[Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats)

it is for:

> Participate in a site (vote, post a question, post an answer, etc...) while it's 2017-12-20 (the last day of Hanukkah 2017) anywhere in the world. The hat was first triggered on 2017-12-19 10:00AM UTC.

Enjoy your secret hat!

Comment: Only `!` after `>`